# zoom_start option does not work without a location in folium

Tags: python-3.x, folium

Very simple question here.
I want to display a world map using python's folium library.
Here is the code I run to do so:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(height=1000, width=1000, zoom_start=2)
m.save("folium_1000_1000_map.html")
```

I then open the saved *folium_1000_1000_map.html* in my browser (firefox), and here is the result:
[image]

The zoom_start option does not seem to work.
I would like the map to display like the next screenshot without having to click on the + button to zoom in once, like I have to at the moment.
[image]

I have tried to open the *folium_1000_1000_map.html* in chrome, it does not change anything. The *zoom_start* option seems to only work when a *location* parameter is specified, but this is not specified in folium doc. Any idea on how to work around this issue ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

And the answer, as simple as it gets, is:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[0,0], height=1000, width=1000, zoom_start=2)

m.save("folium_1000_1000_map.html")
```